# Unresolved use of identifer

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm working through the swift tour in Xcode 6 beta 4.

When I try to use the empty array or empty hash literal syntax it throws this error: Unresolved use of identifer

```
shoppingList = []
occupations = [:]
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already defined shoppingList and occupations you need to do so. You can define them as variables (their values can be changed) like so:

```
var shoppingList = []
var occupations = [:]
```

or constants (their values can not be changed once assigned)

```
let shoppingList = []
let occupations = [:]
```

In your case, the [Swift Tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html) assumes you already have this code:

```
var shoppingList = ["catfish", "water", "tulips", "blue paint"]
shoppingList[1] = "bottle of water"

var occupations = [
    "Malcolm": "Captain",
    "Kaylee": "Mechanic",
]
occupations["Jayne"] = "Public Relations"
```

When you add this snippet:

```
shoppingList = []
occupations = [:]
```

Since shoppingList and occupations have already been defined as variables, you can reassign them to different values.

Comment: It produces a new error - Cannot convert  the expression's type Array  to type ArrayLiteralConvertible

Comment: also under what context would you want to use let for an array that is permanently empty...I am assuming that what you mean is the value of an empty array constant will remain forever empty

Comment: I can't think of any. I just used it as an example from your snippet to show that you can create constants or variables

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either keyword 'let' or 'var' in your variable declaration. Use 'let' if the variable is  read only, use `var` otherwise.

Relevant Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_565)